# How to assure two vectors which will be passed in constructor size equals?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

I implemented a class:

```
public class TableInfoGroup {
  Vector<TableInfo> tableInfoVector;
  public TableInfoGroup(Vector<String> tableNameVector, Vector<String> tableTagIdVector)
  {
    if (tableNameVector.size() != tableTagIdVector.size())
      return;//I think it's not proper to do this
    tableInfoVector = new Vector<TableInfo>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tableNameVector.size(); i++)
      tableInfoVector.add(new TableInfo(tableNameVector.get(i), tableTagIdVector.get(i)));
  }
}
```

How to do that elegant? Throws a exception? Thanks.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou a constructor doesn't have a return type, but in the byte code it would appears as `V` for `void`

Comment: @PeterLawrey oh, sure! My fault )

Comment: @SashaSalauyou it is unusual to use `return;` in a constructor ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, this `return` confused me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would make the method throw an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

For example:

```
if (tableNameVector.size() != tableTagIdVector.size())
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("tableNameVector and tableTagIdVector " +
                                     "must have the same size");
```

Even though `IllegalAgumentException` is an [unchecked exception](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Unchecked_Exceptions), I would still add it to the method's [`throws` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) as documentation.

Making a constructor throw an exception will prevent the object from the being constructed, which I would argue is the correct course of action in this case.

Comment: Funny that a NPE suggests to throw an IAE. :-) (Btw: It's the correct suggestion.)

Comment: I would add that throwing an exception is the only way of preventing that an instance is returned by the `new` operator. In case that the user requires that an object is always created (v.g., at least for logging purposes), a `valid`(or similar) flag could be used (but the programer would have to deal with more complex logic).

Comment: @SJuan76 Another approach is to have a builder class with an isValid() method to check the combination of values is correct.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I considered your builder class way: I got a `TableInfoGroupBuilder builder`, `builder.build()` will get returns a `TableInfoGroup`. If `builder.isValid()` is `false` and call `builder.build()`, what result will get? A `null` Object?

Comment: @Sayakiss it would throw an exception, but you would be able to dermine if you get a valid object before you call it.  A trivial example in the JDK is `Optional` and `isPresent()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey It would be a runtime exception or checked exception?

Comment: @Sayakiss good question. If it's a coding error, and calling `Optional.get()` without `isPresent()` is a coding error, you would make it unchecked.  It may also produce a checked exception if it not a coding error, but is a runtime condition which the caller should think about and might handle.